# Woocommerce save_account_details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce `form-edit-account.php`, i have the following but would only like to retain the Password and Confirm new password fields. I deleted all fields except Password and Confirm new password field but there is a validator that prompts me to fill up First Name, Last Name, Email address fields. How do i disable the validator for that? Really need help on this. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
/**
 * Edit account form
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;
?>

<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

<form action="" method="post">

    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="password_1"><?php _e( 'Password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="password_2"><?php _e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p><input type="submit" class="button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php _e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details' ); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I do that using this:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );

function custom_override_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['first_name']);
     return $fields;
}
```

It will remove the "First Name" field from both, billing and shipping address.

Answer (score 3):

After some quick research, the solution to exactly your problem, and also resently my problem.

Just add this to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields','custom_woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields' );
function custom_woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields( $required_fields ) {
unset($required_fields["account_first_name"]);
unset($required_fields["account_last_name"]);
return $required_fields;
}
```

It will remove the First Name field and Last Name field from the condition of required fields. Of course you can do that with all of your required inputs.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove these validation manually.

Woocomaerce->includes->class-wc-form-handler.php
 find function

```
save_account_details()
```

edit this function or you can remove validation form here.

Comment: Thanks @Yatendra. That works well but is there another way not to edit the core file? like adding some action to functions.php? Thanks

Comment: Hi, i am also looking for a solution for this, how can i remove the validator without touching the core files?